# Display "NaN" instead percentage value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, formatting, number

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and developing a custom view using SharePoint Designer 2007.

I've a column of a table that should display numbers as percentage. Minimun value is 0, maximum 100.

In SP Designer I'm using the suggested code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(@Probabilit_x00e0_, &quot;###0,%;-###0,%&quot;, &quot;lcid1040&quot;)" />
```

But, unless I insert a number like 0 or 100, I always see "NaN". No default value is set.

Why?

Comment: format-number() expects a number, if you give it something else it will return NaN (Not a Number) error, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I insert "20" (without quotes, obviously), I see NaN. The value must be 0 or 100, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the formatted number first and then check for a NaN value.

```
<xsl:variable name="myValue" select="format-number(@Probabilit_x00e0_, &quot;###0,%;-###0,%&quot;, &quot;lcid1040&quot;)" />
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string(number($myValue))='NaN'">0</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$myValue" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This will switch out NaN for a zero.

Answer (score 0):

When using "format-number", it expects a period separator for decimals. With the percentage field (LCID 1036 for french), the decimals separator is a comma.

I had to translate the comma to get it working correctly. I haven't checked if it is the same thing for 1033 or 1040 in this case.

```
format-number(string(translate(@PercentField,',','.')), '#,##0%;-#')
```